# Add text with FFMpeg drawtext at specific time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, drawtext

I'm adding text to an animated GIF.

I would like the text to appear at a specific time, though, and I'm unable to do that.

This is what I have:

```
ffmpeg -i image.gif -vf 'drawtext=textfile=/path/to/text.txt:x=0:y=0:fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=64:fontcolor=white:borderw=3:bordercolor=black:box=0'
```

I tried different approaches, but nothing seems to work. I can manipulate timing for the video using things like `-itsoffset 00:00:30`, but not the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use timeline editing.

```
-vf 'drawtext=textfile=/path/to/text.txt:x=0:y=0:fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=64:fontcolor=white:borderw=3:bordercolor=black:box=0:enable='between(t,23,31)''
```

Comment: Ha! I tried that, but your suggestion made me look at the code again, and my problem had to do with escaping commas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct. And here's the link to the documentation with exemples [Timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing)